# Не обновляется вид на странице (html) при вводе новых значений в инпуты

Tags: javascript, html, json

Пытаюсь вывести новый список объектов на страницу (обновить html), когда ввожу новые значения в инпуты и кликаю кнопку на странице по-прежнему отображаются объекты с введенными первый раз значениями. Дебажила код, ошибок нет. Буду благодарна любой помощи.

```
Данные для инпутов:
campaignType = 'NEW';
utility = 'ComEdEle.Tara';
vendor = 'JEMSCI;UnitedEnergyServices'

Для отображения нового списка:
campaignType = 'NEW';
utility = 'NICOR';
vendor = 'JEMobile'
```

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EvgeniyaP/Products-json/master/products.json';

const elem = document.getElementById('products');

const campaignType = document.getElementById('campaignType');
const utility = document.getElementById('utility');
const vendor = document.getElementById('vendor');
const sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendBtn');

sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getJSONProducts();
});

const getJSONProducts = () => {

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed!')
    }, networkError => {
      console.log(networkError.message)
    })
    .then((array) => {

      array.forEach((obj) => {

        const {
          CampaignOfferTypeID,
          UtilityCo,
          CpiAuxiliary1
        } = obj;

        if (CampaignOfferTypeID === campaignType.value && UtilityCo === utility.value && CpiAuxiliary1 === vendor.value) {
          elem.innerHTML += `<div style="color: red; margin-top: 10px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 18px;">Product</div>`
          for (prop in obj) {
            elem.innerHTML += `<div>${prop}:${obj[prop]}</div>`
          }
        }
      })
    })
};
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input id="campaignType" type="text">
  <input id="utility" type="text">
  <input id="vendor" type="text">
  <button id="sendBtn">SEND</button>
</div>
<p id="products"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elem.innerHTML = html; // !!!
```

```js
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EvgeniyaP/Products-json/master/products.json';

const elem = document.getElementById('products');

const campaignType = document.getElementById('campaignType');
const utility = document.getElementById('utility');
const vendor = document.getElementById('vendor');
const sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendBtn');

sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 getJSONProducts();
});

const getJSONProducts = () => {

 fetch(url)
 .then(response => {
     if (response.ok) {
       return response.json()
     }
     throw new Error('Request failed!')
   }, networkError => {
     console.log(networkError.message)
   })
   .then((array) => {
     var html = "";
     array.forEach((obj) => {

       const { CampaignOfferTypeID, UtilityCo, CpiAuxiliary1 } = obj;
       if (CampaignOfferTypeID === campaignType.value && UtilityCo === utility.value && CpiAuxiliary1 === vendor.value) {
         html += `<div style="color: red; margin-top: 10px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 18px;">Product</div>`
         for (prop in obj) {
           html += `<div>${prop}:${obj[prop]}</div>`
         }
       }
     })
     elem.innerHTML = html; // !!! 
   })
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
       <input id="campaignType" type="text" value="NEW">
       <input id="utility" type="text" value="ComEdEle.Tara">
       <input id="vendor" type="text" value="JEMobile">
       <button id="sendBtn">SEND</button>
   </div>
   <p id="products"></p>
  
   <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь! работает)

Comment: @Kylinko Пожалуйста. Успехов!